# How to incorporate programs into blog

Tags: java, blogs

I've never had a blog, and would like to start one, but before I do, there's one question that I can't find the solution to. How do I incorporate a program into a blog? In other words, I have written a command line hangman game in Java. How do I make the game playable on the blog?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: in Java you mean with swing? then you have to make an applet or javawebstart..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I make the game playable on the blog?

Embedded in the web page?  Applet - expect paint: much pain.

Free floating, launched from a link in the blog?  [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) - less pain, though still a steep learning curve, as you'll probably end up tossing the current code and writing it fresh.

Comment: lol, what do you mean by pain D:>

Comment: I mean steep learning curve, difficult deployment, and constant maintenance.  And that was *before* the recent security updates.

Answer (score 3):

You have a bunch of options:

- provide the sourcecode + binary so that anyone can download and run by themselves
- implement your Java code so that it can run in a Java Applet
- or re-implement it in JavaScript / HTML so that it can just run in browser

Comment: +1 for JS/HTML.  There is really no need for Java, just to create an Hangman game.